# How should I complete the installation of my flooring where a gap remains against the wall?

Tags: flooring, laminate-floor, laminate

I am laying laminate flooring in a room and unfortunately my calculations were off and I am left with expansion gaps of about 2.5cm to 4.5cm (0.97in to 1.77in) along one wall (see picture).

Is there any recommended way to fill this in so that my baseboards can be installed?

[image]

Comment: Rip pieces of the flooring and slip them in. Do you have some left over?

Comment: @JimStewart: Yes, I have leftover laminate boards that I can rip to fit in the gap. They’ll be very narrow though, so I am worried there may be some kind of structural problem along the wall. What do you think?

Comment: Those on this site experienced in installing laminate flooring will surely answer exactly how to do this.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. My guess is that if you support these strips reasonably well they'll be fine, as nobody steps on that area of the floor.

Comment: @DanielGriscom what do you mean when you write “support these strips reasonably well”? How can I make sure they have support?

Comment: I mean something that isn't easily compressible; wood, or perhaps hard foam. Something that, if you pressed down with your fingers, the strips wouldn't rock back and forth.

Comment: I assume that in a floating floor there is supposed to be a gap between the edge of the floor and the wall (~1/4" to 1/2" ?) that would be covered by the baseboard and shoe molding.  What do the installation instructions for this flooring say?

Comment: @DanielGriscom Thanks for explaining! There’s already a moisture barrier and IKEA NIVÅ subfloor below. I think that should be enough, no?

Comment: @JimStewart The installation instructions are sparse to say the least (it’s IKEA TUNDRA), but there’s definitely supposed to be a expansion gap of ~1/4” to 1/2”. I am yet to get the shoe moulding, will have to check that out tomorrow.

Comment: One detail of installation that I can *imagine* (never having installed one of these floors myself) could be that in case of a gap larger than could be covered by baseboard, the narrow strip needed would be *glued* to the adjacent full strip and *temporary* blocks wedged in the gap to hold the strip while the glue dries.  Of course, if the planks in your floor are all glued to each other, you would naturally do this. Are they glued?

Comment: @JimStewart There’s no instructions to glue it, as far as I know. They do, however recommend gluing the baseboards to the wall.

Comment: Is this standard tongue and groove (presumably seated with a mallet) or is this the type that "clicks in" and is locked in place? Are there no instructions on how to handle the final edge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up ripping the laminate boards lengthwise using my jigsaw and fitting them in like Jim suggested. I used some cardboard to cut out the shape that the long pieces should be and then drew across the edge of the cardboard piece on the laminate boards. It worked out quite well I think and I hope there won’t be any structural support issues.

The expansion gap between the wall and laminate boards is now a lot smaller.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a floating floor, when you rip the pieces and install them they will be partly covered by the mouldings. This is the normal way to install this type of flooring.